# Can we exchange hats next Winter Bash?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Since people in the past (and myself in the present) have reacted negatively to certain hats, e.g. "Trucker".

In the spirit of the holiday, when so many take gifts back to stores and exchange them, could we be given the ability to exchange hats starting next Winter Bash?

Maybe you can only exchange one per season, maybe the hats you can exchange to are completely separate from the hats you can earn, I don't know. Just throwing an idea out there.

Comment: Hats are given in response to activities, eg edit 5 old questions. How would that work? Would you exchange one of your hats to 'pretend' you _edited 5 old questions_?

Comment: Or are you saying there should be hats that can't be unlocked the regular way and you'll have to give up one of yours to exchange for it?

Comment: @FirstOne As mentioned in my question: "maybe the hats you can exchange to are completely separate from the hats you can earn"

Comment: Well, english is not my first language, so ambiguity is very common when you walk in my shoes...

Comment: It's like exchanging edits count, reputation, or anything else that is the reason for getting a hat. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @FirstOne No, not saying what you mention in your second comment.

Comment: @MarounMaroun To me it makes sense in the context of the Christmas holiday here in the US.  The day after Christmas, December 26th, is extremely busy in retail stores, because people are bringing back gifts they got, to exchange them for something else

Comment: If you don't like a hat, what's wrong with just not wearing it? You can only wear one hat anyway.

Comment: So you'd want to exchange a hat which you've earned by doing something for a hat which you haven't? Why not just ignore the first hat and do what you can to get the second?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Same old hackneyed response on meta, whether to this particular question, or any other: what's wrong with the way it is?  That adds nothing to the discussion

Comment: @JonClements I said no such thing, please read the question again.  The hats you exchange to wouldn't be for anything you earned, besides I guess whatever you did to earn the hat you are exchanging from.  Winter Bash is supposed to be "fun" and "in the holiday spirit" -- exchanging gifts at retails stores certainly falls under the second in the U.S.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I read it several times - I'm not sure how else to read: *when so many take gifts back to stores and exchange them, could we be given the ability to exchange hats starting next Winter Bash?*... Unless I'm supposed to read between the lines of: *? Maybe you can only exchange one per season, maybe the hats you can exchange to are completely separate from the hats you can earn, I don't know* ? For a feature-request - this is rather vague and doesn't really elaborate of why this would be a great future to have...

Comment: @GeorgeJempty It certainly adds something to the discussion. If there's a clear objection to our current way, that increases the need to change something and might increase the validity of your question. I assume with your snarky response, you mean no, there's nothing wrong with the current way, you just want to change it because you believe this adds something

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth No, my response, snarky or otherwise, is my reaction to so many kneejerk responses just like yours, in the comments to so many meta posts.  "That's not how things currently work" is *never* an appropriate response to a feature request

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Well, can you explain to me why it's irrelevant if the current situation is a problem or not? It seems very relevant to me.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty keep it civil - let's not have this post go down the same route as your last post about hats...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth IT'S A FEATURE REQUEST

Comment: @JonClements Explain to me how I'm not being civil, or do observations that you don't like make them such?

Comment: It's not a very specific feature request - it reads as "Should be be able to swap hats.... I don't know how"? You should at least be specific as to how it'd work and why people would want it... Otherwise, the answer is "no - we don't need to swap hats"...

Comment: @George well - that last comment is a fairly good example and referring to others' comments as "kneejerk responses" - hardly puts yourself across as open to debate and willing to make your post an actual feature request...

Comment: Well, ordinarily, when requesting a feature, you describe the current situation, your request, and how your request would improve upon the current situation. I'm trying to get you to tell me WHY you want this feature, outside of "maybe we could do this"

Comment: _"Maybe you can only exchange one per season"_: What would be the point? Hats aren't a "commodity". There's no way to earn more hats when you "traded" one away. There'd be no way to get _all_ the hats.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty and, from the Feature request tag wiki : "Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature." So Erik's question is very sensible here, from the angle of "what is the benefit of your feature?". We all know Stack developers don't have infinite time, and I'd like to know what you think the perceived benefit of this is if I am to put my vote in its favor.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty The current situation is *completely* relevant to *every* feature request. Feature requests should exist because of a problem with the current situation, and often a misunderstanding about the current situation is the reason for a bad feature request being created.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the analogy is correct:

> [...] in the spirit of the holiday when so many take gifts back to stores and exchange them, could we be given the ability to exchange hats starting next Winter Bash?

People go to stores to exchange their goods for ones that were already for sale (available). Then you say:

> [...] maybe the hats you can exchange to are completely separate from the hats you can earn

This would mean some hats are locked and no activity would be able to unlock them. This breaks the analogy / comparison.

---

I guess what I'm basically saying is that this doesn't have to reflect the real world - specially since the analogy would mean stores having products that can't be purchased directly, only through giving up a (un)wanted gift.